# Exec Tar Function not implemented error

Tags: php, windows, windows-7, exec, tar

```
exec('Tar -zcvf ddat.tg uploads 2>&1', $output);
var_dump($output);

$valarray(2) { [0]=> string(57) "Tar: Nie mogę rozwidlić procesu(could not split? the process): Function not     implemented" [1]=> string(42) "Tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now" }
```

This is the error im getting. I added this to system variables C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin . Why I get such error? I use windows 7 and latest xampp

Answer (score 0):

My Questions:

1. Did you add `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` to the variable `$Path`? AND did you restart your shell?
2. Can you use `"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\tar"` instead of `Tar`?

Comment: exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\tar" -cf output.tgz repository ', $output);
var_dump($output); this works but it somekind takes ages to create a 800mb tgz is there a faster method or anything? Is there a possibilty to get a progress bar or something how much % its done

Comment: there may be.. but this is another question.